# plugin for plotting 2d 3d in eclipse C/C++

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, plot, eclipse-cdt

Well i want to plot data from my arduino serial port to 2d and 3d and i can not find any plugin for Eclipse to do it internal.Is there any? Also is there any other program that can do it easily without using Matlab that needs lisence etc?

Comment: Install `octave`. It's free and almost 100% analogue of matlab. Also read `man gnuplot`: it's a powerful tool for 2D- and simple 3D-plotting. If you want to get beautiful results, use mathGL.

Comment: can it be use inside eclipse?

Comment: For what purpose? Eclipse is IDE, why do you want plot graphs by it?

Comment: it is for calibrating and visualizing an IMU that i work with.I saw that everyone uses python or other programs but i do not want to mess with that at the moment i need to get 2d and 3d plotsfrom the data  i send to serial port.This is all

Comment: i am also using windows at work

Comment: I can't give you such answer: I don't use instruments not on purpose. On my mind IDE is for code creation and terminal is for code running. And you should specify that you using windows in tags or in question body!

Comment: Yes i know i forgot but i ask for a plugin inside Eclipse C/C++ that can plot as there are in python for eclispe and as there is BIRT for java Eclipse